# Mouse scroll not working under VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, scroll, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox, mousewheel

I've got win7, installed VitrualBox, and on virtualbox I've installed Ubuntu 12.04. But I can't use mouse scroll under ubuntu installed on virtualbox. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the solution described there:

https://codeghar.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/mouse-scroll-wheel-doesnt-work-in-fedora-17-in-virtualbox-4-1-10/

edit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-vmmouse.conf

and add this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "vmmouse"
        MatchIsPointer  "on"
        MatchTag        "vmmouse"
        Driver          "vmmouse"
        Option          "Buttons" "5"
        Option          "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```